# Isometric embedding of an $n$-point equilateral space

Tags: metric-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm stumped on these questions, and would appreciate a solution:

I need to find an isometric embedding of the n-point equilateral space in $l_{p}$.

And if $n=2^{d}$, an isometric embedding of the n-point equilateral space in $l^d_{\infty}$.

Comment: Can you please define your terms and notation? Assume we know what "isometric embedding" means and nothing else.

Comment: Sure. "n-point equilateral space" is a space of n points with the same distance between every two points (an n-clique graph). l_p is a vector space of the p-norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $n$ vectors from the standard basis of $l_p$ to find an $n$-point equilateral space in $l_p$.

How many corners does the unit cube in $l_{\infty}^d$ have?

Comment: I have thought of your first suggestion, but if I take n vectors from the standard basis of lp, the distance between every two vectors would be different than 1, wouldn't it? Thus making the embedding not isometric...

Comment: @user83155: Multiply the vectors by a suitable scalar.